# How to bulk find/match and update records using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, entity-framework, linq

Basically, I have an *Items* table in the database where the stock of the items needs to be updated frequently. I have the updated stock values in an XML feed.

That doesn't necessarily mean that the number of items in the table and the XML feed have to be the same. I currently have about **9K** items in the database, and **72K** items in the XML.

Here's what I tried so far:

```vb
Using context As New QuotationDbContext
    For Each item In context.Items.Where(Function(i) i.Active)
        Dim matchedNode = 
            xDoc.Descendants("item").   'xDoc is an XDocument object.
                 FirstOrDefault(Function(n) n.Attribute("itemcode").Value = item.ItemNumber)
        If matchedNode IsNot Nothing Then item.Stock = matchedNode.Attribute("stock").Value
    Next
    context.SaveChanges()
End Using
```

..and the other way around:

```vb
Using context As New QuotationDbContext
    For Each itemNode In xDoc.Descendants("item")
        Dim itemNumber As String = itemNode.Attribute("itemcode").Value
        Dim matchedItem = context.Items.FirstOrDefault(Function(i) i.Active AndAlso
                                                                   i.ItemNumber = itemNumber)
        If matchedItem IsNot Nothing Then matchedItem.Stock = itemNode.Attribute("stock").Value
    Next
    context.SaveChanges()
End Using
```

The problem is that both methods take a little more than 2 minutes to do the "matching and updating", while updating all the items takes a couple hundred milliseconds, hence clearly the matching is what's taking all that time.

**So, Is there a better (quicker) way to bulk match/find records in the database for updating?**

I think the solution to my problem is more likely to be a pure LINQ solution *not necessarily connected to EF*. I wanted to provide the full context though, just in case I'm missing something.

**P.S.** Although my code is in VB, any answers with C# code is very much appreciated as well.

Comment: Not an answer, but I've used this for bulk operations and it seemed to work: https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.Extended

Comment: Nice library for bulk update / bulk delete, but my requirements are different. I think the solution to my problem is more likely to be a pure LINQ solution _not necessarily connected to EF_. I wanted to provide the full context though just in case I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is mostly algorithm problem.
You spend a lot of time to look up the item in your xml.
Here:

```vb
Dim matchedNode = 
        xDoc.Descendants("item").
             FirstOrDefault(Function(n) n.Attribute("itemcode").Value = item.ItemNumber)
```

Try to get all items from your xml to a dictionary for example. Because dictionary spends O(1) time to find element. It would be something like this <s>(I do not have IDE to try this code)</s>:

```vb
Dim dict = xDoc.Descendants("item").ToDictionary(Function(n) n.Attribute("itemcode").Value)

Using context As New QuotationDbContext
    For Each item In context.Items.Where(Function(i) i.Active)
        If dict.ContainsKey(item.ItemNumber) Then
            item.Stock = dict(item.ItemNumber).Attribute("stock").Value
        End If
    Next
    context.SaveChanges()
End Using
```

Comment: How was I so stupid! Great use of `Dictionary`, thank you! Let me just edit your code a little bit to make it compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) option. I would create a stored procedure with merge implementation and [import](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx) it in entity context. 
This will probably give you the best performance results, if implemented correctly of course.

Comment: Umm, never used SP with code-first before. Will give it a try though, thank you!